# Enumerability and diagonalization

Tags: elementary-set-theory, diagonalization

I'm taking a course dealing with Boolos' "Computability and Logic" and I'm stuck on a particular homework assignment. Where $\mathbb Z_{>0}$ is the set of positive integers, prove that the set of all one-to-one, total functions from $\mathbb Z_{>0}$ into $\mathbb Z_{>0}$ is not enumerable.

Knowing that 1-1 means not repeating, into means that some elements may be missing, and a total function means no undefined elements. How would I approach this?

Comment: Welcome to Mathematics Stack Exchange.  Are you familiar with [Cantor's diagonal argument](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cantor%27s_diagonal_argument)?  Assume you have a list of functions from $\mathbb N$ to $\mathbb N$ and then produce one that's not on the list

Comment: Yes, I'm having trouble finding out how to create a function in which duplicates are negated since it's 1-1 function.

Answer (score 1):

HINT: Make it strictly increasing **and** make sure that if your functions are $\{f_n:n\in\Bbb N\}$, then $f(n)>f_n(n)$ for each $n\in\Bbb N$. I’ve spoiler-protected one way to do this.

> Let $$f(n)=1+\max\big(\{f(k):k<n\}\cup\{f_n(n)\}\big)$$ for each $n\in\Bbb N$.